# replace .php file extensions with .html extension using unix

Tags: unix, build-script

I am creating a build script to sweep through .html files after they are generated, I cannot seem to find out how to get this to work. Here is a snippet:

```
for PAGE in ${PAGES[@]}
do
    echo "\t\t\t- $DIR_PRE$PAGE.html"
    echo "\t\t\t- cleaning links in $DIR_PRE$PAGE.html"
    php helper.php output lang=$GET+environment=prod+page=$PAGE > $SITE/$DIR_PRE$PAGE.html
    find * -name \*.html -print0 | xargs -0 sed --in-place -e 's~.php~.html~g'
done
```

the last find command is supposed to find links with the .php extension with in the .html file and replace it with .html but I get this error:

> sed: illegal option -- -
>   usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
>          sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
>               - wiiu.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to rename all .html files to .php in current directory recursively:

`find . -name "*.html" -exec rename .html .php {} \;`

Edit: misunderstood the question. You can use sed to replace strings within files:

`sed -i 's/.html/.php/g' *.html`